# Sort by custom field (MySQL date format) when mixing date and text?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sorting

I use a Wordpress grid plugin to display my review posts and sort them using a custom field where I add the date in the custom field in the post like this: January 1, 2022 (%M %d, %Y). But in some reviews, I don't have a release date and use T.B.A (to be announced) and these always sort themselves at the top. Is there any clever way to make these go to the bottom or will I have to add some random date to them (which I want to avoid).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to save dates in  the proper mysql qway yyyy-mm-dd for sorting and making calculatios

your problem can be easy solved by change the value in the order the way you need

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytb(mydate varchar(50))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytb VALUES('January 1, 2022'),('December 1, 2021') ,('December 5, 2021'),('TBA')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM mytb 
> ORDER BY CASE WHEN mydate = 'TBA' THEN '999-21-31' 
>                            ELSE STR_TO_DATE(mydate,'%M %d, %Y') END ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> | mydate           |
> | :--------------- |
> | December 1, 2021 |
> | December 5, 2021 |
> | January 1, 2022  |
> | TBA              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4cd2293eae4c00c8417ae2900660789)*

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am not a developer. I can only add the format into the settings of the plugin. I guess that limits me quite a lot. Probably best to talk to the plugin author?

Comment: STR_TO_DATE is a bit slow, and so we recomend to save it in the normal mysql Way. The veloper should be aable to save it in the right  format, but your question is answered?